# Login screen on macOS Sierra suddenly with gray background

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

yesterday after waking my Macbook Air (Early 2015) with macOS Sierra from sleep I was greeted with gray login screen. Now I have gray every time I wake up my Mac.

First time I had the same color as background on dock for some reason but that went away after I disabled "Reduce transparency" in Accessibility settings.

I did some googling and found that this may be related to FileVault (since everything is encrypted OS presents gray background) however I had FileVault turned on since I got my Macbook and never encountered this gray thing.

What is the cause? My main worry is that it might indicate some problems with my computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When your machine restarts with FileVault enabled, the gray screen login is to unlock FileVault. There are no problems with your machine.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont get how come I did not see gray login screen before? I certainly did restart a lot of times in my approx. nine months with my machine..